# How to populate a JSP form using AJAX/Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to populate a JSP form using AJAX/Javascript/PHP. I want it to work so that while the user inputs an ID, ajax populates the other 3 fields if the ID matches one from the DB, but so long all I get is "undefined" fields whenever I type an ID (documento) in my form. I've already checked and the output of the php script and it is in the right format (i.e XXXXX,XXXXX,XXXXX,XXXX), so I think my issue is with my Ajax function:

```
function CreateXmlHttpObject() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();//creates a new ajax object
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//this is for IE browser
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");//this is for IE browser
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;//error creating object
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
} 
function ajaxPersonas(documento)
{
    var http = CreateXmlHttpObject(); // function to get xmlhttp object
    var strURL = "http://localhost/formpersonas.php?documento="+documento;
    if (http){
        http.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (http.readyState == 4) { //data is retrieved from server
                if (http.status == 200) { // which reprents ok status                    
                    var results = http.responseText.split(",");
                    $('#nombrep').html(results[0]);
                    $('#apellido').html(results[1]);
                    $('#nacimiento').html(results[2]);
                    $('#documento').html(results[3]);
                }
                else
                { 
                    alert("Hubo un problema con el XMLHTTP:\n");
                }
            }            
        }        
        http.open("GET", strURL, true); //open url using get method
        http.send(null);//send the results
    }
}
```

My PHP script. I'm still not quite sure how to send the '$param' parameter from the JSP file:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$con = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sisben user=postgres password=posgres");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . pg_error());
}

if (strlen($param) > 0) {
    $result = pg_query("SELECT primernombre, primerapellido, fechanacimiento, numeroidentificacion FROM tpersonas 
     WHERE numeroidentificacion LIKE '%$param%'");
    if (pg_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        while ($myrow = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
            $nombrep = $myrow["primernombre"];
            $apellido = $myrow["primerapellido"];
            $nacimiento = $myrow["fechanacimiento"];
            $documento = $myrow["numeroidentificacion"];
            $textout .= $nombrep . "," . $apellido . "," . $nacimiento . "," . $documento;
        }
    } else {
        $textout = " , , ," . $param;
    }
}
echo $textout;
pg_close($con);
?>
```

And finally my JSP form. Notice I use the id field of every text input to pass the corresponding values:

```
<form name="formpersonas">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Documento:</td>
  <td><input id="documento" type="text" onKeyUp="ajaxPersonas();"
        name="idnum"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre:</td>
  <td><input id="nombrep" type="text"
        name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apellido:</td>
  <td><input id="apellido" type="text"
        name="surname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fecha de Nacimiento:</td>
  <td><input id="nacimiento" type="text"
        name="dob"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="reset" value="Clear"></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Forgive me any obvious mistakes, I've been learning to program for just a few weeks now ;)

Comment: in `onreadystatechange` look what is in `results` with the code `console.log(results);`

Comment: @mmm everytime I input a character in my ID field, console outputs a [""] row whether the ID matches or not one in the DB. Is my PHP script not reaching the ajax function?

Comment: please DON'T use this in a public facing site. You DON'T escape the string in the query which makes SQL injection a possibility!!!

Comment: @mic thanks for the warning, I'm learning about injection now.

Comment: look @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php for a safer solution :)